# get and store each interaction into database twilio proxy

Tags: php, proxy, twilio

i want to store each new conversation (from each participant added into proxy service ) into my database.

As I have set `outOfSessionCallbackUrl="http://example.com/create_session`", this `URL` is called when there is no session between the sender and receiver, this is working fine.

I tried to set proxy `CallbackUrl="http://example.com/store_conversation`" to get each interaction. but it is not working. how can i get each message from proxy conversation? I'm using `twilio php sdk`.

```
 $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

 $service = $twilio->proxy->v1->services
                         ->create(array("uniqueName"=>"myService",        

"outOfSessinoCallbackUrl"=>"http://example.com/create_session,
"callbackUrl"=>"http://example.com/store_conversation"));

//When come "outOfSessinoCallbackUrl"=>"http://example.com/create_session
public function create_sessino(){
  header("content-type:application/json");
        ?>
         {
             "uniqueName":"my_service",
             "ttl":"1000",
              "participantIdentfier":"+1965XXXXX"
         }
    <?php
}

//When come "callbackUrl"=>"http://example.com/store_conversation"
 public function create_sessino(){
  //Want to eet and store conversation here
}
```

Comment: please show some code you tried.

Comment: i have updated the question , let me know if still any confusion

Comment: Is `sessino` a wanted typo?

Comment: session is my function name, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get a callback for each interaction you should use the [`interceptCallbackUrl`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/service) rather than the `callbackUrl`. Though make sure you return a successful HTTP response, as a 403 will stop the interaction from completing.

Comment: Hey evangelist, thanks for your valuable response, can you please tell how to return http response to interceptCallbackUrl.

Comment: In the same way that you were set up to respond to the `CallbackUrl`.